# Is there any way to exclude a dependency from its parent?

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, artifactory

So there is a dependency that my project needs, and it is in our internal artifactory, however, after adding the dependency, it started throwing the following error:

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.codehaus.fabric3.api:commonj:jar:1.1.0: Failure to find
>   org.codehaus.fabric3.api:parent-pom:pom:1.0 in
>   http://maven/artifactory/libs-snapshot was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of art_central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I realized that the parent of that dependency ( org.codehaus.fabric3.api:parent-pom:pom:1.0) is not in our internal artifactory.

I know my question might not sound logical and it doesn't make much sense but; **is there any way to exclude the parent or make this dependency not look for the parent?** I already try with the  tag.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: First the dependency is search in a snapshot repository which looks like some configuration issues...furthermore if you project needs it than you have to have it in your repository..otherwise you are not able to build your project as you already realised...

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude a specific file from being searched on a remote repository by using the include/exclude parameters of the remote repository. 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Common+Settings#CommonSettings-IncludesandExcludesPattern

By adding this file, Artifactory will not search for it on the specific repository.